# Get content of web pages and compare

Tags: bash, shell

can someone help/correct me to write a shell script, here is what i'm trying to do

- get content of web pages
- compare content
- if the content are same then return 0
- if not return 2

here is my code

```
for cluster in $CLUSTERS
do
    for applis in $(eval echo \$${cluster}_APPLIS)
    do
       CONTENT=$(wget -q -O - "http://$server/$applis")
       if [ "$CONTENT" -eq 1 ]
       then
       exit_code=0
       else
       exit_code=2
       fi
     done
done

[[ -z "$error_server" ]] && error_server="aucune"

case $exit_code in
    "2")
            echo "CRITICAL - App Version Mismatch"
            exit 2
            ;;
    "1")
            echo "WARNING - instance(s) indisponible(s)"
            exit 1
            ;;
    "0")
            echo "OK - All apps have the save version"
            exit 0
            ;;
    *)
            echo "CRITICAL - there's something wrong with this script ..."
            exit 2
            ;;
esac
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated

Regards
Fab

Comment: sorry for the wrong tag, i ve changed it to the correct one

Answer (score 0):

You can use diff to compare two versions of the file. The first variable is used to get the first version of the web page. I'm not sure whether first should be initialised inside the first loop or outside.

```
first=1
for cluster in $CLUSTERS
do
     for applis in $(eval echo \$${cluster}_APPLIS)
     do
        if [ $first -eq 1 ];then
             first=0
             PREV_CONTENT=$(wget -q -O - "http://$server/$applis")
        else
             CONTENT=$(wget -q -O - "http://$server/$applis")
             diff $PREV_CONTENT $CONTENT
             PREV_CONTENT=$CONTENT
             result=$?
        fi
        if [ "$result" -eq 0 ]
        then
           exit_code=0
        else
           exit_code=2
       fi
    done
```

done

Comment: thanks for you quick reply
I think I was not very clear in my previous message 
Actually we have 4 web servers (Cluster) host the same web page
What I need to do is get the web page content of all my server into a variable and check if they match 
If yes return 0 or return 2

Comment: Edited the script - not sure what     
    for applis in $(eval echo \$${cluster}_APPLIS)
is for. Possibly it could be simplified.